# send sms to server from android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-sms

is it possible to send data from an sms app to a server (e.g a mobile server) when there is no internet, in which the server then sends the sms to the cloud. And if there is internet the sms goes straight to the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

You can create [your own SMS Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511070/build-an-own-sms-gateway) and program it however you like in order whenever you receive a SMS to send a HTTP request to the origin server.

As for the second task, you will need to check whether the device is connected to the internet or not, before you choose whether to send a SMS or HTTP request.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @A. Badakhshan.  Is the third system you are referring to, an sqlite database? Like it stores it on the phone through the sqlite and then I could have like a column which indicates if its 0 or 1. 0 means that the device is offline so it stores and when it becomes online which is 1, it sends it to the internet as so as it becomes active?

Comment: Thanks too @Menelaos Kotsollaris, thinking through it already.

Comment: I tried to add a schema that explains the process; see update!

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to send an sms to the server directly, but you can have a third system that listens to sms messages. So when the device is offline, sms will be sent to that and then It will send the received to the desired server.

Comment: No, I don't mean that. What I am saying is that if you want to send sms to cloud immediately, this third system has to be an sms server which receives your sms and sends it to the cloud. My answer and @Menelaos-Kotsollaris are same.

Comment: Oh! awesome, thanks both of you. But, won't I need to tell my users to signup or download an sms server app on the phone alongside mine before I can actually get this approach to work?

Comment: You are the one who should implement the logic on both app and sms server. Your users won't need to be even aware of your sms server.