# How can I make sms web service on python to send sms to every where?

Tags: python, django, sockets, sms, makeappx

I want to make a sms service(sms API) on python I don't how can I make this to send sms to every where?

Comment: If you want to send sms from python, You can try looking into Twilio and wrap it's send endpoint in a rest api call. But if you want to send sms without any third party dependency its going to be much more difficult, Look into this answer for reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511070/build-an-own-sms-gateway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SMS services as [AWS SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/sms-pricing/) or as mention Twilio or many others actually, any of those are paid services. In order to build your own web service, first, you need to have the hardware to do it. As a basic recommendation, you can use raspberry pi and a [GMS hat](https://www.waveshare.com/gsm-gprs-gnss-hat.htm), code a python script to handle the ATT commands required to send SMSs, and then you can wrap everything with an awesome API using again, python, to create your cloud SMS sender API.

Comment: No twilio is fiter for me and I want to use it for my applicayion and I need it every much